# PHP removing common words from an array

Tags: php

How would you remove common words (the, is, a, as) from the the English language in PHP from an array?

Example of an array could be

```
$story = array("Jack", "is", "going", "out", "to", "play");
```

Comment: What have you tried till now??\

Comment: show that array at first

Comment: and what is expected output of this array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to preserve the content of the array and have it empty if you replace everything in every element...

```
$common = ["the", "as", "is", "a"];

foreach($array as &$element) {
    $element = str_replace($common, "", $element);
}
```

This should work. Let's say you have your content in `$array`, we are looping on it and remove from each element the content of `$common` which you can customize as you need.

Otherwise, if you have to "pop" the element ("pop" for "remove completely")...

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
   if (in_array($v, $common)){
      unset($array[$k])
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset the array

```
    $unwanted_array = array("a","the","un");

    foreach ($your_array as $key=>$value) {
       if (in_array($value,$unwanted_array)){
          unset($your_array[$key])
       }
    }
```

Or you can also try using `array_diff`

```
    $your_array = array_diff($your_array  $unwanted_array );
```